# Hyperlinks break the spoiler code.

Tags: bug, status-completed, spoilers

I just went to update another spoiler-included thread, to add [the new spoiler code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1191/add-markdown-support-for-hidden-until-you-click-text-aka-spoilers).  It seems anything that is a hyperlink is not hidden by the code.  Can this be fixed?

> Here is [the link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4271/197) to the thread in question.

Comment: Sadly it's not a good example any more because I took the spoiler off the first paragraph; the first para was not technically a spoiler and it just served to obscure the question from people.  But I can confirm that yes, the hyperlinked text was showing up non-spoilered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is completed, but may require a hard refresh <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd> to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!